# Simple Sum Program Android java

Tags: java, android, for-loop

No errors, compiles, no run time error.
Hey, I have a simple question about Android sum. I'm doing a simple summation, the code compiles, it does technically do what it suppose to do, sum the number until its greater than 120. However, I wanted the output to show each sum as it goes through the loop. Unfortunately, it just jumps immediately to the last sum on the textview. I tried using a sleep function, wait function, but what ended up happening was it would wait the amount of time for all the loops until the sum was greater than 120, then output the final sum. In this case 4950. Any suggestions for showing each sum on the text view?

I also tried using this line of code, which worked in showing each sum individually, however, it started the timer immediately. Which it should not do. 
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SUM:"+sum1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Basic goal of my simple application
1) Show each sum 
2) When the sum is greater than 120 start timer

Question: How do I get it to show each sum individually on the text-view instead of jumping to the final summation?

```
    public void onClick(View v) 

                for(i=0;i<100;i++)
                    {
                        sum1 = sum1 + i;
                            sum.setText("Sum:"+sum1);
                        if(sum1 > 120)

                            {
                            timer.start();
                            }
                    }

    }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you want to show each sum individually one at a time, or do you want the view to show all of the sums?

Comment: Individually one at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my proposed solution :D

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start counting" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final long SUM_DELAY = 100;

    private TextView mResultView;
    private Button mStartButton;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private int mSum = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mResultView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView);
        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private Runnable sumTask = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            mSum += 1;

            if (mSum > 120) {

                mSum = 0;
                mStartButton.setEnabled(true);

                return;
            }

            mResultView.setText(String.valueOf(mSum));

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, SUM_DELAY);
        }
    }; 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == mStartButton.getId()) {

            mStartButton.setEnabled(false);
            sumTask.run();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it "Jumps" to the last one is because the act of clicking runs the for loop while blocking the UI thread. You are in effect not able to see the text changing, but its changing. You can accomplish what you need by using a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) or [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html), which basically creates a separate thread for you. It also handles the delays which you need. Simply do the math in the Timers execution method.

```
//make sure these are global
int i = 0;
int sum1 = 2;//not really sure where your sum starts so you choose

TimerTask leTask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    sum1 = sum1+i;
                    i++; 
                    /*I don't actually remember if you must go back to the main thread
                    * when in the tasks run method. Incase you get an error because
                    * of that then just do that quickly. I have included a link for
                    * you on how to do that if necessary.*/
                    sum.setText("Sum:"+sum1); 
                    if(sum1 > 120){
                        /*Start your actually timer here
                        * and stop execution of leTask by calling the cancel method*/
                    }         
                }
int delay = 0;//you don't really want a delay since you want it immediately after click
int everySecond = 1000;
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(leTask, 0, everySecond);
```

Keep in mind the way I set ti up is just an example. You should make sure that you have access to `leTask` (or whatever you call it) when its cancelled. `i` and `sum1` should also be global. `delay` and `everySecond` don't have to be in variables. I did that to kind of explain what they do so it makes a bit more sense. I like this method better because you aren't worried about UI thread stuff with the exception of updating the TextView.

Edit: You can also access the UI from the timer using the [post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method from `TextView`. It would look something like this:

```
sum.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        sum.setText("Sum:"+sum1);   
    });
}
```

**EDIT2:**

---

I have to include this edit to be thorough for future user who come across this as I just found out that `Timer` and `TimerTask` is no longer becoming the preferred method for scheduling commands, etc. It should be `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` now. Although this has been the case for some time it hasn't really been reported much in questions on here that i've come across. In either case, android has it in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html). It's literally like the second sentence.

Comment: I should probably add that using a timer would be much easier. Although using a thread, sleeping, and updating the UI is exactly the process that you need, a Timer has that basically built in with the exception of updating the UI. So using a timer to fire every 2 seconds or something and then firing the last timer to do whatever it is that you need seems a lot easier.

Comment: Would I simply define a timer, and then place it after the sum.setText line?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `onClick()` runs on the UI thread. That means that the whole method has to be finished before the UI can update again, hence the sudden jump to the last number. That is also the reason why nothing happens when you use `Thread.Sleep()`. `sleep()` applies in that case to the UI thread, so the whole app will freeze.

If you want the TextView to count up, you have to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Add the loop and a `Thread.sleep()` to `doInBackground()`, publish the progress and set the text in `onProgressUpdate()`. The link actually contains a nice example that should work for you.